# My site is blocked within my office network because address associated with that site has recently been associated with malicious activity

Tags: .net, networking, azure, dns

I am not able to access my site from my office network. It is accessible everywhere else.
The following message shows up when I try from my office network. The site was functional until yesterday morning.
I am hosting the site on Azure Cloud platform. Is it possible that could be due to another site hosted on the same system, since malware activity can only be traced by IP address.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks..

Edit:- I tried calling Cisco too. but they are asking for some customer service details which do not apply in my site. Hence they are not able to help.

This Page Cannot Be Displayed

---

Based on your corporate access policies, this web site ( http://radiq.org/ ) has been blocked because it has been determined by Web Reputation Filters to be a security threat to your computer or the corporate network. This web site has been associated with malware/spyware.
Threat Type: othermalware 
Threat Reason: IP address is either verified as a bot or has misconfigured DNS.
If you have questions, please contact your corporate network administrator and provide the codes shown below.

---

Notification codes:     (1, MALWARE, othermalware, IP address is either verified as a bot or has misconfigured DNS., BLOCK-MALWARE, 0x00d76885, 1409160200.302, AAAD8QAAAAAAAAAAJf8ACP8AAAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAE=, http://radiq.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is working now- and as I suspected the problem was due to another site hosted on the same Azure server, since malware activity can only be traced by IP address. I got a dedicated Ip for myself and now I am good to go.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That site was blocked by the corporate's firewall access policies - 'web reputation filters'

I would suggest contacting the system administrators where you work in case you really need to access the site from within the work place.

By first glance, radiq.org is a Radiology Simulation and Training website.
What bothers the system seems to be a misconfigured DNS.

Comment: I did that of course..